# Why changing orientation triggers event for another time?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which uses text-to-speech engine to speak out given text aloud. Here it is:

```
public class AfterPassword extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private String message = "This message will be spoken out.";
    static final int TTS_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.afterpassword);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, when speaking has end, and by chance user changes the screen orientation, the speaking starts again. I want to stop this speaking on orientation change.

Comment: Please read the Android Activity life cycle documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity is destroyed and re-created when orientation is changed. This happens to all UI components. A Service on other hand, stays over orientation changes. [Use an Intent Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) and post Intents with text massages to it. You can place the TTS code in `onHandleIntent()`.

Answer (score 1):

On an orientation change, the application restarts. Try saving the state of your application before a change in orientation or lock the screen in portrait or landscape mode.